# javascript html label displaying incorrect values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string that coming from a database something like this `test&nbsp;(test<sup>&reg;</sup>)` that I would like to display in a label. I try to parse the text but it displays just the last value in the string. I did try to set the `innerHTML` value to the string and that didn't display any value.

> Is there any other way to fix this?

```
    strHTML = $.parseHTML('test&nbsp;(test<sup>&reg;</sup>)');
    var Name = "";
    $.each(strHTML, function (i, el) {
      Name = el.wholeText;
    });
    $(".lbl-drug").text(Name);
```

Comment: Use `$("...").html(html)` to set HTML, otherwise you're just setting the text without html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
strHTML = $.parseHTML('test&nbsp;(test<sup>&reg;</sup>)');
$(".lbl-drug").html(strHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="lbl-drug"></label>
```

Comment: is there even a need for the parseHTML ?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers